# OpenGL only displays textures loaded within method?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glut

I've got a method called showMainMenu() in my Render class.
In Render I've defined my textures as bitmaps

```
Bitmap* bBall;
Bitmap* bWall;
Bitmap* bStart;
Bitmap* bEnd;
Bitmap* bHighscores;
Bitmap* bHelp;
Bitmap* bStar;
```

In my ctor of Render I do:

```
this->bBall = new Bitmap("ball.bmp");
this->bEnd = new Bitmap("beenden.bmp");
this->bStart = new Bitmap("starten.bmp");
this->bStar = new Bitmap("star.bmp");
this->bHelp = new Bitmap("hilfe.bmp");
this->bHighscores = new Bitmap("highscores.bmp");
this->bWall = new Bitmap("wall.bmp");
```

In showMainMenu() i bind the texture in the following way:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Texturen aktivieren

//draw Start button
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->bStar->texture);
```

But my display stays white :(
When I load the texture inside my method

```
Bitmap m = Bitmap("star.bmp");
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m.texture);
```

I can see the texture.
Why isn't the 1st working?

Comment: There is too little information to go on here. Where do you generate texture objects, where do you load the texture data, do you use shaders and if so where do you send the sampler, ...? Try to provide a stripped down, minimal working example that shows your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is, that you're creating the `Bitmap` instances before creating a OpenGL context. Then the Bitmap file will be loaded, but no texture object generated. Easiest way to fix this: Upon instanciation of Bitmap (i.e. in the constructor) just load the file data and set the texture ID variable to 0. Add a method `bindTexture`, which calls glBindTexture for you (you should do this anyway, that's how OOP is supposed to work). But also add a test if the texture ID zero and generate the ID and texture before binding then.

Example:

```
void Bitmap::bindTexture()
{
   if(!textureID) {
      glGenTextured(1, &textureID);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_..., textureID);
      upload_texture_data();
   } else {
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_..., textureID);
   }
}
```

BTW: Accessing class members via `this->` is considered bad style, and there's absolutely no reason for doing it that way. Heck even casting the `this` pointer to a base class won't give you its virtual methods, because implicit upcasting is the whole point of virtuals.

Comment: Don't forget to bind it before uploading the texture data inside the if.